# Customize categroy catalog page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, templates

In "appearance > customize > woocommerce > product catalog" I choosed to display the categories for the shop display page.  This wokrs fine and the categories are now shown on the main shop page.

BUT, I want to change the html output like I was able to do it for the product loop in content-product.php tempalte.

For example I changed the `<li>` to `<div>` in the content-product.php tempalte and I want to do the same with the category loop output. How can I do that.  It seems so simple but I can't find it.  The category loop output is still `<li class="product-category product"> ...` and can't find where to change this.

THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`content-product_cat.php` is the equivalent template for the category thumbnails. You want to copy `templates/content-product_cat.php` to your theme and modify it, the same way you presumably did for `content-product.php`. As with the product template, though, the only HTML in the template is the `<li>` tag. The rest is output through hooks.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was it.  I knew it was simple, but because I couldn't find this file in the plugin woocomerce template directory I was a bit lost.  Thanks ;)